# How can I set some functions to run while the AppState is inactive in react-native

Tags: react-native

I try to add a number to a variable in the databas when the AppState is inactive and I do not know what to do

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', () => this.handleAppStateChange())
```

```
handleAppStateChange(){
    if(AppState.currentState === 'inactive'){
        addIncome().then().catch(error => {})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `add` and `remove` AppState change listener in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`:

```
state = {lastAppState: AppState.currentState};

componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}
```

And also you need to save the latest `AppState` in state and check it when `AppState` changes, to find out when it changes to `inactive`:

```
handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  if (
    this.state.lastAppState === 'active' &&
    nextAppState.match(/inactive|background/)
  ) {
    // your app state changes to inactive
  }

  this.setState({lastAppState: nextAppState});
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195271/discussion-on-answer-by-sisa-how-can-i-set-some-functions-to-run-while-the-appst).